# how to implement custom footer in faceted search screen in 5.1.1

Tags: alfresco-share

we need to customize footer to keep it build version in facted search screen in 5.1.1;i have followed below link.

http://pavelmakhov.com/2016/02/customize-alfresco-footer-aikau

now after implementing  it entire footer was not visible.its calling faceted-search.get.js & custom widget.js;I think there is some problem with custom html file.

custom-footer.html

```
<div class="alfresco-footer-AlfShareFooter" data-dojo-attach-point="footerParentNode">
   <span class="copyright" data-dojo-attach-point="footerContainerNode">
      <a href="#" onclick="Alfresco.module.getAboutShareInstance().show(); return false;">
         <img src="${logoImageSrc}" alt="${altText}" border="0"/>
      </a>
       <span>Buildversion:${buildVersion}</span>
      <span class="licenseHolder" data-dojo-attach-point="licenseHolderNode">${licensedToLabel} ${licenseLabel}<br></span>
      <span>${copyrightLabel}</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

faceted-search.get.js

```
var footer = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel, "id", "ALF_STICKY_FOOTER");

logger.log("footer:"+footer);

footer.config.widgetsForFooter = [{
  name: "blogs/footer/search-footer", config: {
    semanticWrapper: "footer",
    currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
    buildVersion: "2.0.0",
    buildDate: "4th Nov 2016"
  }
}];
```

[image]